# Footer shows up in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css, web

My footer doesnt show up at the bottom, it does on all the other pages except this one(code below). the content in the footer shows up at the bottom(wrong positions of the component, but still at the bottom) but the backgroud color is in the middle of the page.

Here is the code:

```
<footer id="fots">
            <div id="infof">
                <div id="infoc">
                    <ul class="ulfot" id="ulfk">
                        <li><b>Destinatons</b></li>
                        <li>London</li>
                        <li>Sarajevo</li>
                        <li>Istanbul</li>
                        <li>Gothenburg</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="ulfot">
                        <li><b>Flight info</b></li>
                        <li>Before flying</li>
                        <li>When flying</li>
                        <li>After flying</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="fotsd">
                <div id="leftis">   
                    <p><b> &copy something </b></p>
                </div>
                <div id="rightis">
                    <a href="#" id="bks">Back to top <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </footer>
```

here is the css:

```
#infoc{
width: 960px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#fots{
background-color: #ebebeb;
width: 100%;
}
#fotsd{
height: 50px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
width: 960px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#leftis{
width: 300px;
float: left;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#rightis{
width: 300px;
float: right;
text-align: right;
color: black;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#bks{
color: black;
}
#infof{
width: 100%;
height: 180px;
background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you want: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vqxvebf6/)

change this CSS

```
#fots{
background-color: #ebebeb;
width: 100%;
}
```

to this:

```
#fots{
background-color: #ebebeb;
width: 100%;
position:fixed; /*new*/
bottom:0;/*new */
}
```

and change this CSS:

```
#infof{
width: 100%;
height: 180px;
background-color: gray;
}
```

to this:

```
#infof{
width: 100%;
/*height: 180px;*/ /*removed*/
background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#fots {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px; 
   background: #ebebeb;
}
```

Setting the position to absolute should keep it on the bottom, according to [this source](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) (first google result..)

Comment: This kind of works, all of the footer is in one place, but now it is stuck to the bottom of the actuall browser screen, so when you scroll up&down you will always see the footer at the bottom of the browser screen. How do i get it to be stuck at the bottom of the page instead of browser screen? (sorry for long and probably incomprehensible comment)

Comment: @SheikhAbdiMahmood check my answer for that question

Comment: to answer your comment instead of position: absolute, just make sure you put your `<footer ..> ... </footer>` directly before the `</body>` tag in your DOM, and/or look at @dippas answer

Comment: @dippas and J-Dizzle, thank you so much for your answers, but it does still not work. Since the footer works well on the other pages, I suspect it might be a problem somewhere else in the body before the footer code.

Comment: then show us the link of this page, it might be invalid html or missing closing tag.

Comment: upvotes are the thank you of the internets. And yes if it works on other pages then you probably have an unclosed `<div>` or something specific to that page. I'd suggest you use developer tools in your browser (its f12 in google chrome) to find the culprit